# Link static libs to dynamic libs: -mimpure-text in G++ / Ubuntu

Tags: linker, g++, static-libraries, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to link some 3rd party static libraries into a dynamic library. However I get the error -

> relocation R_X86_64_32 against `**TMC_END**' can not be used when
>   making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

On Solaris, you can tell GCC/ G++ to allow linking with code that wasn't compiled with -fPIC, through the option -mimpure-text. (Found via great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589977/linking-a-shared-library-against-a-static-library-must-the-static-library-be-co)) However this option isn't recognized on Ubuntu (16.04, g++ version 5.4.0):

> g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mimpure-text’

Is there any equivalent option, or any other solution except for compiling the 3rd parties static libraries with -fPIC enabled?

Thanks!
P.S Excellent explanation on relocations [here](https://www.collabora.com/about-us/blog/2014/10/01/dynamic-relocs,-runtime-overflows-and-fpic/)